# how to make the button only once click

Tags: javascript, html, css

Guys I put (like and dislike button not with facebook) my site.And I want to show like values and dislike values.I did but I want just once click.How can I do ?

```
  var clicks = 0;
function updateClickCount() {
    document.getElementById("clickCount").innerHTML = clicks;
}





 onClick="clicks--; updateClickCount();
 onClick="clicks++; updateClickCount();
```

I expect the button of once click , but the actual button as much as you want.

Comment: disable it once click and on page load you have to check it clicked already or not.

Comment: You want it as a toggle button? Like on the first click it would do +1 and on the next click, it should do a -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the event listener, after the button gets clicked using [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener). Do keep in mind that the parameters supplied in the `removeEventListener` call must be identical with the ones supplied to the `addEventListener` call, otherwise it won't work.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
button.addEventListener("click", onClick);

function onClick() {
  console.log("Clicked");
  button.removeEventListener("click", onClick);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

If you have added the listener inline (using `onClick=""` attribute), you can't use `removeEventListener`. You can however remove the `onClick` attribute.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("btn");

function onClick() {
  console.log("Clicked");
  button.removeAttribute("onClick");
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onClick="onClick()">Click Me!</button>
```

You could disable the button, making it un-clickable.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
button.addEventListener("click", onClick);

function onClick() {
  console.log("Clicked");
  button.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

You can use a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (Promises can only be resolved once).

```js
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
new Promise(function(resolve) {
  button.addEventListener("click", resolve);
}).then(onClick);

function onClick() {
  console.log("Clicked");
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

Finally you store the info of whether the button has been clicked or not in a boolean variable.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
var buttonFlag = false;
button.addEventListener("click", onClick);

function onClick() {
  if (buttonFlag) return;
  console.log("Clicked");
  buttonFlag = true;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
```

Update

You can now also use the [once property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#once) so that the event only runs once (or never if it's never triggered).

```js
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
button.addEventListener("click", () => console.log("Clicked"), {
  once: true
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create custom like/dislike function, try to check button click with cookies. If you disable button after the button gets clicked, user will be able to click the button when the page is reloaded. 
Check cookie, if it exists - don't process click event, if not - increase/decrease like value and set cookie.
here you can read about using cookies with javascript
[Onclick javascript cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36493716/onclick-javascript-cookie),
[Set cookie and get cookie with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)